# Why $v_a\mapsto D_{v}|_a$ (the directional derivative) is a linear map $\mathbb R^n_a\to T_a\mathbb R^n$?

Tags: derivatives, manifolds

Let $\mathbb R^n_a=\{(a,v)=v_a\mid a\in\mathbb R^n, v\in \mathbb R^n\}$ the set of vector of $\mathbb R^n$ with origin $a$. Let $$D_{v}|_af=D_vf(a)=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}f(a+tv)$$
where $D_v|_a:\mathcal C^\infty (\mathbb R^n)\to \mathbb R$. Let $T_a\mathbb R^n$ the set of all derivatives of $\mathcal C^\infty (\mathbb R^n)$ at $a$.

**Why $v_a\mapsto D_v|_a$ is a linear map ?**

---

**Attempts**

Let $f\in \mathcal C^\infty (\mathbb R^n)$.
$$D_{v+w}|_af=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(a+t(v+w))-f(a)}{t}$$
$$=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(a+tv+tw)-f(a+tw)}{t}+\underbrace{\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(a+tw)-f(a)}{t}}_{=D_{w}|_a f},$$

Now, how can I prove that $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{f(a+tv+tw)-f(a+tw)}{t}=D_v|_af\ \ ?$$

Comment: It is easier to first show that the directional derivative is given by the dot product of the gradient with $v$. Then it follows from the bilinearity of the dot product. In the end your approach is consistent but finishing the proof from where you're at now is not really any easier than it is to do it from scratch in a different way.

Comment: @Ian: Thank you. It's not possible like I tried to ?

Comment: Your attempt will work but the last identity is basically the same difficulty to prove as the original one, so you haven't really made the problem any easier.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

If $v\in \mathbb R^n$, 
$$f(a+tv)=f(a)+t\nabla f(a)\cdot v+o(t).$$